# System Registry Error VB6 running as User Windows 10

Tags: vb6, registry, system

I just recently upgraded to Windows 10 and ever since I have upgraded I can't get into VB6. I keep getting the System Registry error. I have googled and tried about everything and nothing seems to work. Running VB6 as Administrator is not an option, don't ask but we can't have admin to our computers we have to be logged in as users. The way we use to fix it was to trick Windows 7 log on as Admin run VB6 as Admin then switch me back to user and it worked, but this no longer works. Does anyone have any suggestions that currently have VB6 working as a user and not admin? I really don't want to resort to have to run it out of my virtual machine :( Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you can you a similar trick but from your login as opposed to logging in as an admin. When logged in as you, right-click the VB6 shortcut and click Run As Administrator, get an admin to log in, and VB6 should open without error. Close VB6 then try running it without running as an administrator. I think the issue is just on first load as it's trying to create some registry entries which it doesn't have access to do. Once they are created you can run as a normal use.

Comment: Marc thanks for the reply unfortunately that didn't work either :(

Comment: I'm not sure what else you can try. You may have to resort to using a VM if your IT won't allow you to be an admin on your computer. I'm an admin on my machine, which is running Windows 10, but I still do my development in a Windows 7 VM. It's just easier to have full control of the OS and I can also take a snapshot of my clean development environment and revert to it any time I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Amanda, 
I know it is 3 years later and I wonder what you did. and my solution may be late.
I moved VB6 Enterprise to a Windows10 machine, I did not upgrade the machine to Win10 with the IDE. However to make it work for some of my clients with Win10 machines I:

1. Back up all the VB6 files, folder and directories.
2. Using control panel in Win10, uninstall VB6 app. That's right, uninstall!
3. Using the original install disk, running it as an Administrator, install the program.
4. If the program has been updated to a later version, you need to get a copy of the latest version and copy over the one that was installed.
5. Or, Sweet Talk your IT guy into making you a new install disk with the latest version you are supposed to be running.
6. Go to the folder where the exe file is installed, Right Click on it and open the Properties, and go to the Compatibility tab.
7. Choose run as an administrator, and also click the Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP Service Pack3, or if it shows Latest version of Windows XP try that. You may need to check with your IT department.
8. **Warning:** if the VB6 program  uses any non-Microsoft tools you may need to register them by hand.
9. I suspect this has already been worked out for you, but I put it here for anyone that may stumble across it, needing it.